# Navbar responsive and style

Tags: html, css, navbar, responsive

I want to make this type navbar responsive. I showed PC and mobile style.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6V56.png)
Please help me. Thanks

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please add a [repro] of your attempt and state where exactly you are stuck. Please also read [ask]! (no idea how this could be upvoted 2 times).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend you, use [`bootstrap`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar) for making this type of project easier!

---

**but if you want a CSS-only solution here is:**

pc version: [image]

mobile version: [image]

> I added also a comment, so you can understand well

```css
body {
    /* deleting the default margin */
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
    /* setting the height of navbar */
    --nav-height: 3rem;
    height: var(--nav-height);
    /* centering */
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    /*  logo: auto (less space)
        input: all space width
        other: auto (less space)
    */
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
    /* little padding */
    padding: 0 0.5rem;
    /* a gap between elements of navbar */
    gap: 0.5rem;
}


/* css for the menu icon */

.navbar svg {
    height: calc(var(--nav-height) / 2);
    padding: 0 0.5rem;
}


/* css for the container of input and menu icon */

.navbar #second-container {
    display: grid;
    /* menu icon take less space
    input take 100% space */
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
    /* making the container take all the space */
    width: 100%;
}


/* css for the input */

.navbar #second-container input {
    display: grid;
    height: calc(var(--nav-height) / 2);
}


/* css for the other things on the right side of the nav*/

.navbar #third-container img {
    height: calc(var(--nav-height)/ 1.5);
}


/* responsive for mobile devices */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
    .navbar #third-container {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <!-- 1 -->
        <div id="first-container">
            <!-- logo -->
            <span>your logo</span>
        </div>

        <!-- 2 -->
        <div id="second-container">
            <!-- menu Icon -->
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><!--! Font Awesome Pro 6.1.1 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License) Copyright 2022 Fonticons, Inc. --><path d="M0 96C0 78.33 14.33 64 32 64H416C433.7 64 448 78.33 448 96C448 113.7 433.7 128 416 128H32C14.33 128 0 113.7 0 96zM0 256C0 238.3 14.33 224 32 224H416C433.7 224 448 238.3 448 256C448 273.7 433.7 288 416 288H32C14.33 288 0 273.7 0 256zM416 448H32C14.33 448 0 433.7 0 416C0 398.3 14.33 384 32 384H416C433.7 384 448 398.3 448 416C448 433.7 433.7 448 416 448z"/></svg>
            <input type="text" placeholder="search bar">
        </div>

        <!-- 3 -->
        <div id="third-container">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/30" alt="">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/30" alt="">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/30" alt="">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/30" alt="">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/30" alt="">
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: I highly advise using Flexbox instead to vertical center the elements so they look aligned and not out of vertical alignment.